# gnuplot unable to plot a function

Tags: plot, gnuplot

I have the following gnuplot script which does not yield an output

```
set encoding utf8
set termoption enhanced

y(x) = 20 * log10(1/((1/694) * x))

set log x
set xrange [1:10]
set xlabel "{/Symbol w} 1/s"
set yrange [-150:150]
set ylabel "G^* dB"

plot y(x)
```

However, if I replace the `y(x)` function with something simpler, eg. `y(x) = 20 * log10(1 / x)` the script works as expected.

What is wrong with the function and why `gnuplot` is not able to plot it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In integer arithmetic (1/694) is equal to zero, so the argument of the logarithm is 1/(0*x), which is not numerical. To make sure you are using floating point arithmetic try

```
y(x) = 20 * log10(1./((1./694.) * x))
```